# Azure storage poison queue how to see beyond the first 32 messages?

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-queues

I am trying to use the storage explorer to recover a message in the poison queue that according to a trace in app insights failed with a not very descriptive exception message. I would like to get the message so that I can examine it and see if it was malformed or just process it in my local system.

The problem is that the storage explorer only shows me the first 32 messages in the queue, and the ones  am interested in are beyond that. I cannot see a way to specify a search filter so that I can retrieve a different set of messages or even a way to ask for the next page.

So far my best solution was to delete the messages in the queue So I could get to the one I am interested in.

Is there any other way to access this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any other way to access this information?

Not through Storage Explorer but programmatically what you can do is dequeue the messages (32 at a time which is the max limit) with long visibility timeout (default is 30 seconds) repeatedly till the time you fetch the desired messages from the queue.

Long visibility timeout will ensure that you don't end up dequeuing the same message again.